# How to share describe() block in Cypress.io across various files, similar to Mocha's 'Shared Behaviour' facility

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, picocontainer

I am working on a Web-test automation framework, and would like to few functionalities present in `describe()` block in one cypress **..spec.js** file, by methods present in another in another cypress **..spec.js**  file?

Kindly read about **Shared Behaviour** facility provided in Mocha:
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours
[image]
[image]

I tried that but its not working.
1. Is it possible to achieve something similar to Mocha Shared steps (as descibed above)?
2. Or is there something similar to Cucumber-ruby/Pico-container's **WORLD** object?

Kindly advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom commands to re-use steps over several files. This can be done by the following steps.

1. Create a custom command in `cypress/support/commands.js` with the steps which you want to use in several files. You can use this syntax:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('customCommand', function() {
  cy.get('object')
    .clear()
    .type('something')
    // do other steps
})
```

2. After you created the custom command you can use it in the testscripts by this syntax:

```js
describe('Description of the test', function () {
  it('first scenario of the test', function () {
    cy.customCommand()
  })
})
```

Concluding: to share steps over several testfiles, you need to place the shared steps in the commands.js instead of in a testfile.

Comment: There're certain functionalities those are in 'describe()' block that I need to reuse. But those can not be stored as Custome commands, as those are not commands & rather large chunk of code. Kindly advise

Comment: can you provide an example?